# TemplateUrl not displaying the home.html

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Can someone help me on this please, it's not serving the HomeController. it did not print the text inside in my Home.html when I run http://localhost/myangular/

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>

        <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include main.js -->
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {

});
```

home.html

```
<h1>hello home</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **main problem** that I'm seeing with your code is that you're not loading [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) - since AngularJS 1.2.0, ngRoute is separated into its own module.

Steps to fix your problem:

- add ngRoute library: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.min.js`
- add it as a dependency: `angular.module("myApp",["ngRoute"])`

Comment: it's working but why is the video tutorial that I followed is not using the ngRoute dependency ?

Comment: Ah..I see now the ngRoute is separated .thank you for that

Comment: I've just edited my answer. ngRoute was separated into its own module since AngularJS 1.2.0.

Comment: This allows for greater flexibility as you can use other 3rd party libraries (like [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)).

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl:"/templates/home.html",
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});  
});
```

with relative path for templateUrl. I'm just assuming this, I'm not familiar with angular